# How to reset selected values in "multiselect-react-dropdown"

Tags: reactjs, multi-select

How we can reset selected values, like if I want to change selected values.

```
<Multiselect
                  options={this.state.robotTrackers}
                  onSelect={this.onSessionSelectRemove.bind(this)}
                  onRemove={this.onSessionSelectRemove.bind(this)}
                  displayValue="name"
                  closeOnSelect={true}
                  id="selectTracker"
                  ref={this.multiselectRefTracker}
                  placeholder="Select advertiser's tracker"
                  selectionLimit={5}
                  style={multiselectCustomStyle}
                />
```

I am trying this but it only clear all selected values not update.

`this.multiselectRefTracker.current.resetSelectedValues(['1'])`

Comment: share your robotTrackers, SessionSelectremove code please

Comment: robotTrackers is just an array object: const sessionOptions = [
      { name: "Android", id: "Android", select: "OS" },
      { name: "IOS", id: "iOS", select: "OS" },
      { name: "Windows", id: "Windows", select: "OS" },
      { name: "Windows Phone", id: "Windows Phone", select: "OS" },
    ]
onSessionSelectRemove(selectedList: any, selectedItem: any) {
 console.log(selectedItem.select)
}
on some button click I want to reset selected values like this
resetSelectData() {
 this.multiselectRefTracker.current.resetSelectedValues(['Android'])
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry I found Multiselect before discovering [MultiSelect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component), not only is its update mechanism non-standard for React (using createRef instead of setting the element's value) but I found it impossible to get `resetSelectedValues` to work, period.

I know it's not technically an answer to your question, but for anyone else stuck with this I would recommend migrating to MultiSelect instead.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have already migrated to MultiSelect.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right path.

Use `this.this.multiselectRefTracker.current.resetSelectedValues()` instead of `this.multiselectRefTracker.current.resetSelectedValues(['1'])`

I hope this would help you.

Comment: I saved the reference in a state variable to make sure that I was referring to it correctly, and was able to print the contents of `current` to the console, but `resetSelectedValues()` simply would not work for me (whether I ran it "fire and forget" or `await`ed it). After discovering the alternative package, https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component , I haven't looked back.